# Evaluating a matrix with strings to get Eigenvalues

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, linear-algebra, eigenvalue

The main idea is that a user will input 3 strings to create a Hessian matrix, and the value of two or more variables, the goal is to calculate the eigenvalues to know if the matrix is positively define or not.

So far, I've tried replacing the string with an int or using the eval() function on the matrix, but it seems like it's not compatible with a matrices.

Here's an example of the code I have so far.

```
#Hessian
x = 0
y = 0
input_1 = '6x, -3, 0'
input_2 = '-3, 6y, 0'
input_3 = '0, 0, 0'
input_1 = input_1.replace('x', '*x')
input_2 = input_2.replace('y', '*y')
input_1 = input_1.split(',')
input_2 = input_2.split(',')
input_3 = input_3.split(',')

hess = np.matrix([input_1,input_2,input_3])
hess
```

Which outputs:

```
matrix([['6*x', ' -3', ' 0'],
        ['-3', ' 6*y', ' 0'],
        ['0', ' 0', ' 0']], dtype='<U4')
```

Now, the problem is that I can't find a way to replace the variables 'x' and 'y' with the values declared above because these are still strings.

If I could find a way to convert the values of the matrix to integers and replace the values then I would use something like `eigenval = np.all(np.linalg.eigvals(hess))` to calculate the eigenvalues.

Any tips or recommendations on how to change the elements of the matrix would be highly appreciated.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: why do you need to use string, you can use variable x and y directly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write a function to parse the input strings to the required format.

```
def parse_input(instring, x, y):
    xs = []
    for i in instring.split(','):
        if 'x' in i and 'y' in i:
            xs.append(x * y * int(i.replace('x', '').replace(y, '')))
        elif 'x' in i:
            xs.append(x * int(i.replace('x', '')))
        elif 'y' in i:
            xs.append(y * int(i.replace('y', '')))
        else:
            xs.append(int(i))
    return xs
```

Sample run:

```
>>> input_1 = '6x, -3, 0'
>>> input_2 = '-3, 6y, 0'
>>> input_3 = '0, 0, 0'
>>> [parse_input(s, 0, 0) for s in (input_1, input_2, input_3)]
[[0, -3, 0], [-3, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]]
```

Comment: Brilliant! This is exactly what I needed. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

You could take advantage of python's `eval` function which evaluates the value of strings

For example, if your code reads:

```
x = 5
z = eval('10*x')
```

then z would be equal to 50.

You could then use the `map` function to map `eval` onto your lists of strings. If you replace your `split` lines with something like this:

```
input_1 = list(map(eval, input_1.split(',')))
input_2 = list(map(eval, input_2.split(',')))
input_3 = list(map(eval, input_3.split(',')))
```

then your values that contain x's and y's would instead contain whatever number the string evaluates to.

Comment: Using eval may not be the best approach to this problem.  It does not capture the intent of the solution. Besides eval allows the execution of arbitrary python code which is a security risk in code which accepts user inputs.